# How do I fix this scrolling issue in my Logitech MX518 mouse?

Tags: mouse, scrolling, logitech-mouse

My mouse was working fine for more than a year but suddenly scrolling started to behave weirdly. Scrolling seems to have its own life and has started to move up and down quickly making any computer activity impossible. Things I've tried include:

1. Updating drivers
2. Uninstalling drivers and using none
3. Plugging the mouse into different USB slots
4. Cleaning the mouse

None of these helped. Does anyone have a clue how to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

This actually isn't a hardware issue, it's a software issue. I've used this mouse for a long time and it's worked great. I recently bought a second one (so I'd have one to travel with) and installed the latest drivers. Big mistake - ran into the crazy possessed over-sensitive scrolling issues described here. From the Logitech Forums, I found this solution:

1. Uninstall the SetPoint software (currently at v 6.52)
2. Donwload and install SetPoint v 6.32 (available [here](http://www.oldapps.com/setpoint.php?old_setpoint=6731)).
3. In SetPoint, make sure "smooth scrolling" is turned off.

Problem solved.

Comment: I also uninstalled the SetPoint software and this solved the scrolling issue for me. The issue for me seems to be related to running VMs in Virtualbox/VMWare. Perhaps one driver doesn't like the other?

Comment: It was a hardware issue. Confirmed .

Answer (score 4):

I took mine apart and fixed it. 
The scroll wheel has a light sensor on one side and a lens emitting a ray on the other. the light goes through tiny holes on the wheel from one side to the other and the sensor reads the intervals to make the scroll go.

Anyway, if you are technically savvy - carefully open the three screws on the bottom, then carefully open the mouse. My advise is that you take a few shots with your digital camera to make sure you know how to put it all back together when done. then dismantle the scroll wheel (take more shots if required) - carefully clean all the dust and grime, put back together and that should do the trick.

If you're like me and didn't pay attention when you were taking your mouse apart you can watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCkDOAxf5MA&t=15m42s

Answer (score 4):

The answer given about the lens and light sensor being dirty solved my wheel issue.

For me the wheel was very lagged and usually took a full spin just to get a single response or sometimes it wouldn't respond at all.

Open the mouse (three screws under the stickers, and after removing the top cover the wheel lifts up and out. Be sure the lens and sensor are clean (indicated by the red arrows in the image below) - in my case the sensor on the right side was dirty. The wheel now works like new again. I actually had to get used to how sensitive it's supposed to be.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for reminding me about this question by replying to it. It's my fault not providing the answer, which I had indeed found.

I sent the mouse back to the vendor where they tested it and confirmed there was a defect. I was given a new mouse replacement which has served me well for a long time.

It began to behave strangely again now, after nearly five years. The scroll wheel doesn't really scroll sometimes, but I'm still very happy with the overall performance.

Comment: I'm glad you fixed the issue! You can mark this as the accepted answer if you wish. Click the outlined 'tick' under your vote count :)

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a hardware issue.

I mean that or you will need to clean it more intensively, or you will need to get a new one. Because it is most likely due to the mouse wheel sensors being dirty, or simply "tired".

The good point is that Logitech has an excellent support. I recommend you to contact them, to explain the issue. I have a very good experience of their support, they offered in the past to replace my mx1000 which had a malfunction. (They also send you feet for free, you only have to ask the support for this).

The link to the support is [here](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/428/187&cl=us,en&hub=1?selectedcrid=428&selectedcid=187). However, it seems that their mail support is currently being moved, and is unavailable until the 21st of september. You can still call them, though.

**Edit:** Ok, "tired" was a bit too fast, I couldn't find the word I was looking for. I didn't really mean that sensors are tired, rather that mechanical/physical parts could be, for example in the way the mouse wheel is "held". It could be that the "steps" which are originally on the wheel, are not holding correctly, and any move is turning it, even a bit. It could also be that sensors have a problem, and are simply misplaced or too sensitive.

I suggested more intensive cleaning, but I doubt it will be enough. To me, it's likely that you will have to get a new one (sent by Logitech support or not). But it's not something you can really fix by changing drivers or else.

The only thing which you can do, on software side, is to deactivate actions from the mouse wheel so that it won't bother you anymore (I believe this can be done using AutoHotkey, more details on that if this solution interests you). Though of course you would have to do without a mouse wheel, which is quite disturbing.

Comment: It is a hardware issue. I cleaned it very well. Don't know how sensors get tired but I have let them sleep in my drawer for a year or so already.... Yes - support is not working.

Comment: Logitech keeps on losing points imho

Answer (score 1):

yes, it was I suppose at the optical reader of the wheel. Because I have shake it strongly and made a strong blow into the gap between wheel and mouse cover and suddenly the scrolling wheel works again..

I hope that will last a while otherwise I will be forced to open that which I want to avoid

Comment: This does not make sense as an answer, do you want to change it to a comment to someone's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Clean it out.  Take the three screws out under the stickers on the bottom. Slide the wheel and carrier out and remove all the built up dust and hair. When you remove the wheel you can easily loose the ratcheting lock but I prefer mine removed anyway. It speeds up scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

It was the SetPoint software for me.  I uninstalled it and it works fine now. I also learned from [the Logitech site](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/articles/11650), the following:

> **When you don't need SetPoint:**
>
> SetPoint is not required for the following mouse functions that are
>   built into Windows® 8:
>
> - Left click
> - Right click
> - Middle click*
> - Back/forward buttons for navigating Web pages
> - Scrolling**
>
> * If you want to assign other functions to your mouse buttons, then
>   you can use SetPoint to change their functionality.
>
> ** Additionally, if your mouse has a tilt wheel, it will work in
>   most Windows 8 style applications, but you will need SetPoint if you
>   want to scroll horizontally in traditional Windows desktop
>   applications.

So if you don't need any added functionality, don't use SetPoint.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found this thread. In my case scrolling became intermittent then eventually stopped working completely. Seemed odd as the mouse is generally clean, well cared for, and not terribly old. It was useful to know that the sensors for scrolling are optical. I was able to gently push the wheel to each side and blow into the space. It took all of 5 seconds and the problem is completely fixed. If you have a gas duster use that instead. You probably do not want to spit in your mouse.

Answer (score -1):

Well I have tried to shake it and some other violent methods but the problem most likely was in a cable or connectors located near the wheel, not in the sensor or wheel itself. It might be that cables are somehow damaged or broken in a way and some strong shaking could have fix it temporarily but what helped me was to generally straighten them up and try to bend them in a way that made my scrolling work again. Might be simple as that.

Comment: Shaking and "other violent methods" are not recommended ways to fix electronics.  As such, I have to down vote this as an answer.